# How to minify JavaScript files that contains a function name separated with a '.'?

Tags: javascript, minify

I am minfying 100's of Javascript files on a windows OS and ran into a issue with almost half of them. It turns out that the minfiying compressor cannot properly minify js files that has a function spearated by a dot. For the YUI compressor it deletes the contents of the file when such a situation happens, and for Ajaxminifier, it just ignores the dot and take the function name before it.

Example of the function in question:

```
function window.onload() {}

Error Message: :missing ( before function parameters
```

Using the YUI compressor as an MSBuild task and command line both yeild the same results.

Command line example:

```
java -jar yuicompressor.jar --type js --charset utf-8 -o D:\foo.js D:\foo-min.js
```

---

Using the Ajax Minifier example:

Command line:

```
AjaxMin.exe -o D:\foo.js D:\foo-min.js
```

---

However, one solution is to rewrite the function and the minification process works great
Example:

```
window.onload = function() {}
```

But this is not an option for us, right now.
Does anyone know about this problem and able to provide a solution?

---

Thanks. Yes, I did inherit these files and I am yet to determine why it was written this way. I dont believe there is any processor that converts it to proper JS..I do know that the web app only runs on IE, this may be the reason why this is working. On firefox etc, it may not be the case.I am looking to get this changed

Comment: `function window.onload() {}` is not valid javascript. Half of your project is dead code?

Comment: `window.onload = function() {}` is valid JavaScript. If rewriting your code so that it isn't broken is "not an option", you're out of options.

Comment: Why is writing syntactically correct code "not an option"?

Comment: thanks for the responses. I did not write the js code, but inherited them to minify, this is where I noticed the issue. I guess I can push that we re-write them all using valid JavaScript, like window.onload = function() {} .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's breaking because you're trying to minify invalid javascript. Functions cannot have dots in them.

I think you're trying to namespace. If you are, you would be better off doing something like:

```
var myVar = {
    foo: function () { /* do something */ }
}

myVar.foo();
```